# JVM heap and Tomcat heap relation

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, heap-memory

Suppose on my machine [x64, linux, 8g Ram], I set heap at `JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m` and for tomcat as `CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx1024m"`.

Now at any moment, the memory requirement of application in tomcat goes beyond heap size specified at `CATALINA_OPTS`.

Will it give Out of Memory error? OR it will work without an issue as there is plenty of memory given to JVM(by `JAVA_OPTS`)?

Answer (score 2):

When you are running your app in tomcat, then it will use the heap memory specified in the **CATALINA_OPTS** for the tomcat.

**You can have multiple JVM running on the same machine and in this case, there is separate JVM for the tomcat and it's a different Java process.**

Also, to check the memory usage of your application you can use the any profiler tool comes with the JDK. one such tool is [visualvm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html).

**Edit** :- As OP asked what happen if the memory allocated to app is exhausted, then in that case [outofmemory error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) comes.

And using above mentioned profiler tool, you can debug what causes this error and where most of the memory is consumed in your app.

Comment: thanks @Amit Khandelwal but my question is what will happen if memory required by app in tomcat will cross limit given to tomcat? in a situation where there is plenty of memory with JMV heap.

Comment: @d.Mon , then you will get out of memory error https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html